# Why can't the lnk icon show correctly?

Tags: c++, api, shell, com

I tried to create a new shortcut link file using IShellLink and IPersistFIle interface.
After I finish saving the lnk file by calling IPersistFIle::save(), and I want to delete the ico file used to create the lnk right after save function returns. But the problem is that the lnk file is showed in a blank page, not the icon I used.

If I don't call deletefile() after save, the lnk file looks correct.

My question is that when can I delete the icon file after save the lnk file?

PS: I tried to sleep, for, like 2 seconds before delete file, and the lnk looks correct too.

Part of my code is bellow:

```
    hRes = pShellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile,(LPVOID*)&pPerFile);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
        WCHAR wszLinkFile[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0};
    #ifdef _UNICODE
        StringCchCopy(wszLinkFile, sizeof(wszLinkFile) / sizeof(wszLinkFile[0]), lpszLinkFilePath);
    #else
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszLinkFilePath, -1, wszLinkFile, MAX_PATH);
    #endif

        hRes = pPerFile->Save(wszLinkFile, TRUE);
        pPerFile->Release();
    }
    pShellLink->Release(); 

    ::CoUninitialize();

    DeleteFile(lpszIconPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post enough code, but the method name is IShellLink::SetIconLocation().

> **Location**

You delete the icon and the location is no longer valid.

Boilerplate is to use an icon that's embedded in the executable as a resource.  But if you use a separate .ico file then you'll need to keep it valid.

Comment: Hi,Hans the icon I use to create a lnk file is a seperate .ico file, and the parameter in IShellLink::SetIconLocation() is the loaction of that ico file. I tried delete the ico file a few seconds later after save the lnk file, but didn't refresh the icon cache, the ico looks correct, but if I refresh the cache by SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, 0, 0), the lnk file shows in a blank page again. So I think this may be have something to do with icon cache.

Comment: I thought I was pretty explicit.  *Don't delete the .ico file*.

Comment: I know that now, thanks Hans. But I'm curious about the different results. Why do I keep the ico file and delete it a few seconds later after IShellLink::Save and the lnk file, and the link file looks correct?

Comment: The icon cache was not made to act as a backup for deleted icons, it is only there to speed up Explorer.  It is not under your control, you cannot count on any particular behavior or guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer, Hans